# Mapping from $G$ to $S_X$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

If I have a group $G$ and a set $X$ then I can define an action $\alpha:G \times X \rightarrow X$ like $(g, x)=gx$

I can also define it's corresponding morphism $\alpha':G \rightarrow S_X$. Does this have to be suryective?

In the exercise, I have that $p$ is the lowest prime that divides $|G|$, I have an $H$ such that $|G:H|=p$ and $X=G/H$.

I tried thinking an example with something not so abstract, like $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$. So, $p=3$, $H \cong \mathbb{Z_5}$, and $X=\{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \bar{2}\}$. $S_X = \{id, (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{1}), (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{2}), (\bar{1} \text{ } \bar{2}), (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{1}\text{ } \bar{2}), (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{2}\text{ } \bar{1})\}$.

If I have a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ to $S_X$, then, trivially, $\alpha'(0) = id$. Since $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ has order 15, then it has to go to an element from $x \in S_X$ such that $ord(x) \text{ }| \text{ } 15$, so $ord(x) = 3$ or $ord(x) = 5$. But $S_X$ has no elements of order $5$, then it has to go to either $(\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{1}\text{ } \bar{2}) \text{ or } (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{2}\text{ } \bar{1})$. I can apply the same reasoning to every element, so $Im(\alpha')= \{id,(\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{1}\text{ } \bar{2}), (\bar{0} \text{ } \bar{2}\text{ } \bar{1})\} $ so it wouldn't be suryective.

Is this right?

Comment: It's a fine exercise to come up with an action that isn't surjective explicitly. That being said, it's important to know that any homomorphism from a group $G \to S_{X}$ for some set $X$ is a group action and clearly not every homomorphism from a group into a symmetric group is surjective.

Comment: Of course, $ord(x)=15$ is a possibility in general, although it is obviously excluded in this case, for the same reason $5$ isn't possible.

Comment: Presumably, we are talking finite groups here... Are we also taking finite set $X?$

Comment: Yes. G and X are finite

Comment: In practice this homomorphism is scarcely surjective. Weaker assumptions are (multiple) transitivity conditions, or primitivity. On $n$ elements, surjectivity is equivalent to $n$-transitivity (or $(n-1)$-transitivity). Onofri (1927) proved that on $\aleph_0$ elements, surjectitivity is equivalent to transitivity on the set of injective sequences whose image has infinite complement.

Answer (score 1):

No, the morphism has not to be surjective. Consider for example $\alpha: \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined as $\alpha(0,x)=x$ and $\alpha(1,x)=-x$.

Then the morphism $\alpha':\Bbb Z_2\to S_{\Bbb R}$ is not surjective.

Comment: Something I'm not getting is the final part. How would \alpha' be defined? I guess $\alpha'(0) = id$ and $\alpha'(1) = (x \text{ } {-x})$? Could it be something else? Like $\alpha'(1) = (y \text{ } {-y})$ for any other $y$?

Comment: $\alpha'(1)(x)=-x$ so which defines $\alpha'(1)\in S_{\mathbb R}.$ This needs to be proven - that $\alpha'(1)$ is a bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $\alpha'(1)\circ \alpha'(1) = \alpha'(0)=\text{id}_{\mathbb R}.$ @DaniSeidler